# Demo Filters vs. Community Filters

Tags: filter, ag-grid

I am new to working with ag-grid. I am working through some of the documentation, and ran across something I am unclear on. In the Column Filtering section, I see the examples, and I put together some code that I believe duplicates what is done in the example. The code works, and I can filter, but the filter popup I see is not the same as what I see in the examples on the page. Specifically, I see a filter that has a text entry area, and, once text has been entered, an area that shows And/Or buttons (with the buttons on top of the text) and a second text entry area. In the examples in the documentation, I see clear popups with a dropdown starting with "Contains" (and having other options) and a text entry area below. What am I doing wrongly/missing? Is this expected behavior?
My column defs look like:

```
var columnDefs = [
{headerName: "Title", field: "title"},
{headerName: "Alias", field: "alias"}
];
```

And my grid options are:

```
var gridOptions = {
columnDefs: columnDefs,
enableSorting: true,
enableFilter: true,
enableColResize:true,
rowSelection:'single',
rowDeselection:true,
onRowSelected: onRowSelected,
onSelectionChanged: onSelectionChanged
};
```

I am getting the rows from fetch, so rowData is not defined.

The images (first is the one I see in the demo, the second is what I see in my app):

The filter I see in the demo app

[image: The filter I see in the demo app]

The filter I see in my app

[image: The filter I see in my app]

Comment: Can you add some screenshots?

Comment: I see your screenshots, and I don't have a clue what's happening. At a guess, I would say you have some strange CSS that's affecting the ag-grid filter. Try temporarily removing all CSS that isn't native to ag-grid. If you need more help, you'll have to provide a demo that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thx @thirtydot. I will give that a whirl

Comment: @thirtydot spot on. the "select" elements had been undisplayed in some other css, and the inputs had been resized. If you want to put up a solution, I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: The culprit here seems to be materialize.css. Even though I have done a 
"$('select').material_select();" and attempted to add the "browser-default" class to items with the .ag-filter-select class, I am not seeing the select in the filter box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

> I see your screenshots, and I don't have a clue what's happening. At a
>   guess, I would say you have some strange CSS that's affecting the
>   ag-grid filter. Try temporarily removing all CSS that isn't native to
>   ag-grid. If you need more help, you'll have to provide a demo that
>   reproduces the problem.

It seems that [materialize.css](https://materializecss.com/) was the source of the problem:

> @thirtydot spot on. the "select" elements had been undisplayed in some
>   other css, and the inputs had been resized. The culprit here seems to be materialize.css.

You probably need some CSS like this:

```css
.ag-root-wrapper select {
    display: inline-block !important; /* might not need !important */
    /* and any other needed CSS to make selects display normally */
}
```

Comment: I went with a slightly different take on that (attached to the ag-filter-select class directly and added some things like padding:0px and height:20px to get the look I was going for). I ended up adding the styling to the end of my html doc, which handled the issue (for me anyway). Thanks @thirtydot for all the input and help.